# repo2 is a library for repo1

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

In the moment, I have two github repositories, i.e. `repo1` and `repo2`. Both are two django projects created by our team. In `requirements.pip`in `~/work_projects/repo1`, I have the line

```
-e git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/repo2.git@de5622dcf0b9a084f9b0a34cdd1d932026904370#egg=repo2
```

Hence, `repo2` becomes a library used by `repo1` in `~/.virtualenvs/venv/src` (repo1's virtual environment). In the moment, I need to modify both repositories at the same time. My main focus in the moment is that each time I modify `repo2`, I need to test out the results on `repo1`. I want to look at the impact of `repo2` on `repo1` once modified.

I don't want to push my changes on github and reinstall `repo2` on `repo1` each time I want to see those changes. How could I make it works easily, workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar setup and I usually install from file (run from console):

```
pip install -e ../repo2
```

And since you said git, and you also said you don't want to push, but nothing about committing, here's a version that can install your library from a tag, branch or commit in a local git repo:

```
pip install -e git+file:~/work_projects/repo2@develop#egg=repo2
```

Comment: @J.Doe Updated with your repo names, but I cannot verify right now if git+file accepts a path with tilde (I know it's picky about relative paths).

Comment: Don't worry, everything work fine. Forget my question